# Listener on a Web Page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, web-services

Is there a way for a web page to respond to a message from a web server, while idle? I need to display a page of user information. As a user swipes his card, a system will authenticate him, and then send a message to my solution, indicating that a user authenticated.

I then need to update a web page with his details. So, no interaction with the page from the user. It must just refresh when I send a message to it - somehow. Is this possible?

I was thinking of some sort of page which has 'subscribed' to events from a server, allowing me to send it, maybe a JSON object, and when it receives this message, refreshes the screen with the data from the messages it recieves?

We don't want to poll the server every second. We need to it respond to an incoming event. So, listening, as opposed to asking. and it has to be quick. So, the only delay would be the amount of time for the message to go from the web server, to the client browser.

We're using .Net application server, standard browser (Chrome, IE etc), a Bootstrap UI (Irrelevant, I guess).

Comment: use the websockets protocol

Comment: Would that be a JavaScript/JQuery implementation on the web page, configured to 'Listen'?

Comment: Here is a good overview on web sockets. It will give you a place to get started at least. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: SignalR if you are looking for something higher level than WebSockets (and need to support for older versions of IE).

Comment: Does WebSockets (or SignalR) poll the server? Or does this create a pipe of sorts, and just wait for messages from the server? Polling would be an issue - we're hoping the page can 'subscribe' to the server and just wait quietly.

Comment: you have client component and a server side component. After starting communications with http a web socket connection is established between server and client. Listeners are set up at both ends for real time, event driven communications in either direction.